o2switch Node APP : 404 "Cannot GET" URL - works on localhost
I'm encountering an issue with a Node.js application hosted on o2switch.
Whenever I try to access directly certain routes by clicking on a link or refresh the page (F5), I consistently receive a 404 error (cannot GET /exemple).
When i created the node app on o2switch, it created an htaccess with my environment variables.
I have a front on VueJS hosted on the same o2switch moon.
I've checked my routes and they seem to be defined correctly in my code.
Here is my .htaccess, front router/index.js + vite.config.js and back server.js.
Thank you in advance for your help!
# DO NOT REMOVE. CLOUDLINUX PASSENGER CONFIGURATION BEGIN
PassengerAppRoot "/home/sc3ievr8380/quiz-server"
PassengerBaseURI "/"
PassengerNodejs "/home/sc3ievr8380/nodevenv/quiz-server/20/bin/node"
PassengerAppType node
PassengerStartupFile server.js
# DO NOT REMOVE. CLOUDLINUX PASSENGER CONFIGURATION END
# DO NOT REMOVE OR MODIFY. CLOUDLINUX ENV VARS CONFIGURATION BEGIN
<IfModule Litespeed>
SetEnv DATABASE_HOST localhost
SetEnv DATABASE_PASS nonono
SetEnv DATABASE_USER nonono_quiz
SetEnv EMAIL_PASS nonono
SetEnv EMAIL_USER noreply@nonono.fr
SetEnv SERVER_CORS http://quiz.nonono.universe.wf
SetEnv SERVER_PORT 3000
SetEnv DATABASE_NAME nonono_bdd_quiz
</IfModule>
# DO NOT REMOVE OR MODIFY. CLOUDLINUX ENV VARS CONFIGURATION END



front router/index.js
------------------------------

import { createWebHistory, createRouter } from 'vue-router';
import { useAuthentificationStore } from '@/stores/authentification';

const routes = [{
  name: 'login',
  path: '/',
  alias: '/login',
  component: () =>
    import('@/views/QuizLogin'),
    meta: {
      title: 'Keepcod - Login'
    }
},
{
  name: 'quiz',
  path: '/quiz',
  component: () =>
    import('@/views/QuizGame'),
  meta: {
    requiresAuth: true,
    requiresAdmin: false,
    title: 'Keepcod'
  }
},
{
  name: 'admin',
  path: '/admin/login',
  component: () =>
    import('@/views/AdminLogin'),
    meta: {
      title: 'Keepcod - Login'
    }
},
{
  name: 'candidat',
  path: '/admin/candidat',
  component: () =>
    import('@/views/AdminCandidate'),
  meta: {
    requiresAuth: true,
    requiresAdmin: true,
    title: 'Candidats'
  }
},
{
  name: 'recruiter',
  path: '/admin/recruiter',
  component: () =>
    import('@/views/AdminRecruiter'),
  meta: {
    requiresAuth: true,
    requiresAdmin: true,
    title: 'Recruteurs'
  }
},
{
  name: 'quizs',
  path: '/admin/quiz',
  component: () => import('@/views/AdminQuiz'),
  meta: {
    requiresAuth: true,
    requiresAdmin: true,
    title: 'Quiz'
  }
},
{
  name: 'ranking',
  path: '/admin/rankings',
  component: () => import('@/views/AdminRanking'),
  meta: {
    requiresAuth: true,
    requiresAdmin: true,
    title: 'Classements'
  }
},
{
  name: 'profile',
  path: '/admin/profile',
  component: () => import('@/views/AdminProfile'),
  meta: {
    requiresAuth: true,
    requiresAdmin: true,
    title: 'Profil'
  }
},
{
  name: 'check',
  path: '/admin/quiz/:id/:email?',
  component: () =>
    import('@/views/QuizGame'),
  meta: {
    requiresAuth: true,
    requiresAdmin: true,
    title: 'Quiz'
  }
},
{
  name: '404',
  path: '/:pathMatch(.*)*',
  component: () =>
    import('@/views/NotFound'),
    meta: {
      title: 'Page introuvable'
    }
}
];

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(),
  routes
});

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {

  const store = useAuthentificationStore();

  document.title = to.meta.title;

  if (to.name == "admin" && store.isAdmin) {
    next('/admin/candidat');
  } else {
    if (to.meta.requiresAuth && !store.isAuthenticated) {
      next('/login');
    } else {
      next();
    }
  }

});

export default router;

------------------------------
back src/app.mjs
------------------------------

import express, { Router } from 'express';
import cors from 'cors';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import servConfig from './config/server.config.mjs';
import { sendError } from './controllers/common.controller.mjs';
import quizController from './controllers/quiz.controller.mjs';
import adminController from './controllers/admin.controller.mjs';
import manageController from './controllers/manage.controller.mjs';

const app = express();

// Permet d'autoriser un domaine à accéder aux ressources
if (servConfig.CORS) {
  app.use(
    cors({
      origin: servConfig.CORS
    })
  );
}

// parse requests of content-type - application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json());
// parse requests of content-type - application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

// Permet de définir l'ensemble des routes du serveur
route(app, quizController, '/quiz');
route(app, adminController, '/admin');
route(app, manageController, '/manage');

/**
 * La route en cas d'erreur
 */
// La signature de la function doit toujours comporter 4 arguments
// eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
  console.error(res);
  sendError(res);
});

export default app;

/**
 * @private
 * Permet de créer une nouvelle route
 *
 * @param {Express} app - L'application express
 * @param {Function} controller - Le controller définissant les différentes chemins
 * @param {string} path - Le chemin racine
 */
function route(app, controller, path) {
  let router = Router();
  controller(router);
  app.use(path, router);
}

------------------------------
back server.js
------------------------------

loadServer();

async function loadServer() {
    const { default: app } = await
    import ('./src/app.mjs');
    const { default: servConfig } = await
    import ('./src/config/server.config.mjs');
    const { default: db } = await
    import ('./src/models/database.mjs');

    db.sequelize.sync();

    const PORT = process.env.PORT || servConfig.PORT;
    app.listen(PORT, () => {
        console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}.`);
    });
}

------------------------------
front vite.config.js
------------------------------

import { fileURLToPath, URL } from "node:url";

import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import vue from "@vitejs/plugin-vue";

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  base: "/",
  plugins: [vue({
    template: {
      compilerOptions: {
        isCustomElement: (tag) => ['lord-icon'].includes(tag),
      }
    }
  })],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "@": fileURLToPath(new URL("./src",
        import.meta.url)),
    },
    extensions: [".mjs", ".js", ".ts", ".jsx", ".tsx", ".json", ".vue"], // add .vue extension
  }
});




the o2switch doc says "Then you need to create a .htaccess file so that URLs of type /something are interpreted by the index.html file" but if i edit the htaccess to add this, it crash
Options -MultiViews RewriteEngine On RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f RewriteRule ^ index.html [QSA,L]

Does the routing work when you run it locally?

"but if i edit the htaccess to add this, it crash" - please explain properly, what that actually means - "it crash."

@Nahom yes everything works fine locally

@CBroe idk, like for exemple if i try to connect /admin/login, i get this error : "TypeError: can't access property "token", s is undefined", the POST request get a 200 response code but nothing in the response
